# QuickOSM using wild cards on lines (rivers)

Tags: quickosm, wildcard, toponyms

I'm trying to find all rivers with a name containing specific word (or part of it). F. ex. all *'Danube-'* rivers, or *'Danu-'*, *'Dan-'* and so. In another topic I've found useful query, which after example modification looks like this:

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="250">
<union>
    <query type="nwr">
        <has-kv k="river"/>
        <has-kv k="name" regv="Danube(.*)"/>
        <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
</union>
<print mode="body"/>
```

and it finds nothing.

I tried also this:

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="250">
<union>
    <query type="nwr">
        
        <has-kv k="name" regv="Danube(.*)"/>
        <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
</union>
<print mode="body"/>
```

and it will find all *'Danube'* restaurants and hotels, but not the river itself.

Can someone explain to me how to find also rivers (lines)? I need it for my historical research (toponymy). I might add I'm not great at coding.

**Edit:** Danube was just an example. I don't need Danube itself, but other rivers and wild card is a must.

I'll give you better example - I'm searching for the *'Stob-'* rivers and I need query which will find rivers like *'Stob-nica'*, *'Stob-ianka'* and *'Stob-niczanka'* and others 'Stob-' rivers whose suffixes I don't know. Can't do that without wild card.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, the key `name` is using the local language. So in Germany, it's written `Donau` and not `Danube`. So your regular expression needs to be more complexe and you would need to check all names.

Example in Germany:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/203099955

Instead of looking for the name "Danube", I would use the relation ID of the river :

- go on OpenStreetMap.org website
- Use the `Query features` tool and click on the Danube itself.
- It will show you that the river belongs to a OSM relation ID 89652

This is the link to the Danube relation: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/89652

Use QuickOSM to download this relation by writing in the query tab:

```
<osm-script>
  <id-query ref="89652" type="relation"/>
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
  </union>
  <print/>
</osm-script>
```

This will give you the river, no using wild cards which might be wrong.

Note, the relation should be complete in OSM to use this technique. You might have a look to the relation in JOSM or in QGIS to detect gaps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however _'Danube'_ was just an example and not very fitting I guess. I've edited my main question to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've made it:

```
[out:xml][timeout:250];(way["name"~"Stob(.*)"]["waterway"]({{bbox}}););out body;>;out skel qt;
```

It will find all *'Stob-'* rivers like *'Stobxyz'*, *'Stobzyx'* and so. Works like a charm:-)